# Hash key for Facebook SDK if not using Single Signon?

Tags: android, facebook, hash, authentication, key

I really see no reason to use the single signon feature because the Facebook app is just so fragile on Android anyway that it doesn't work a lot of times.

With the above said, do I need to generate and register the hash key with Facebook if I'll have the user login via the WebView login interface anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, at least not last time I checked. They only added that hash-key field to the settings as of the Single-Sign-On release of the Facebook SDK; requiring it would have broken a lot of older apps.